# Saving Image as OLE Object, in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a table with a field that is of type OLE Object.  I then have a form with a number of fields.  Some are just text fields.  But, I also have an Image object on the form.  When a user clicks a button, a dialog opens and they can pic a photo.  Once they select the photo, the Image object displays that picture.  I want to save that image to database.  What I have only seems to save a reference to where the file is located, on the computer.  So, this would not work if the db is moved.  Here is the code I have:

```
Dim wrkCurrent As DAO.Workspace
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim rstPerson As DAO.Recordset

Set wrkCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set dbs = CurrentDb
Set rstPerson = dbs.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_person WHERE id =" & ID)

With rstPerson
 .Edit
      !bio_photo = Me.Image37.picture
 .Update
End With
```

How would I save the image file to the OLE Field, so that I could load it back to the Image object, on the form, at a later time?

Thanks

**Answer:**

So, what I ended up doing was following this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210486 [EDIT: that link is now dead, try [this](https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/210486) instead]

I use the readBLOB function to read the file and save it into the database.  Then, when I run a report or open a form that has the picture, onload, I use the WriteBlob function to write the file to a temp folder and then use that path to populate an Image object.

Comment: The link the OP provided is no longer online, however, the article is still available in the Microsoft KB Archives here: https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/210486

Answer (score 1):

Databases can grow to enormous sizes when you start embedding images, leading to slower queries, crashes, timeouts, and dissatisfied users. Use OLE with caution when adding images into a database

Simple Google search has [how to load ole object from folder into table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/158941)

And a search on this site comes up with [auto attach images using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787149/how-to-auto-attach-images-in-access-2010-using-vba-macros)

Comment: Yes, I know saving objects in a table is not always the best idea but we are capping the save to 100kb so I think it will be OK.  And, considering the business case, it's the only option I have.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: So, this method seems to not work for OLE Object field types but for a field that is an Attachment.  I read it was better to save files as OLE.

Comment: Any luck with above url?

Comment: Sorry for not responding.  Switching between projects can make me lose track.  I actually ended up using this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/210486.  I'll post more into my original questsion